# How do I can fetch the email body without downloading the attachment file

Tags: java, api, email

This question is related to Java Mail API and Gmail Account.

I would like to display the message part from the gmail emails by ignoring the attachment file. My code is working properly in case of no attachment, but when it comes to email with attachment, it is not giving output.

I just want the message body from the email to be displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your code which working without attachment and if you have any logs in case with attachment, add it too.

Comment: Here you go http://pastebin.com/vtKcas0K

Comment: Ok, and problem is in part from line 76., is not? Did you try to debug it? Do you know what happens there? I would try it but these informations should be provided by you in your question ;) I will try to debug it when I will have a more free time.

Answer (score 0):

This is only first shot without trying to debug your code, but you could try to follow [original Oracle suggestion](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody):

```
private boolean textIsHtml = false;

    /**
     * Return the primary text content of the message.
     */
    private String getText(Part p) throws
                MessagingException, IOException {
        if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
            String s = (String)p.getContent();
            textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
            return s;
        }

        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
            // prefer html text over plain text
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
            String text = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    if (text == null)
                        text = getText(bp);
                    continue;
                } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                    String s = getText(bp);
                    if (s != null)
                        return s;
                } else {
                    return getText(bp);
                }
            }
            return text;
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                if (s != null)
                    return s;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I think there is problem you are trying to get MultiPart and content from it. 
The code above work only when :

> You can call the getText method with a Message object (which is a
>   Part).

Comment: Where do I add this code in my existing code? I tried adding it but getting compile time errors?